# Timeout error connecting to Sql Express

Tags: c#, sql-server

I try to update a table, but I get this error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated.

This is a part of my code:

```
Image x = Image.FromFile(o.FileName);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
x.Save(ms, x.RawFormat);
byte[] a = ms.GetBuffer();
ms.Close();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\conectare.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagine", a);
cmd.Connection = con;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from login", con);
da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
SqlCommandBuilder obj = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "login");
DataRow dr= ds.Tables[0].Rows[ind1(username)];
dr.BeginEdit();
dr["imagine"] = a;
dr.EndEdit();
try
{ da.Update(ds, ds.Tables[0].TableName); 
 pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(o.FileName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Please try again!", "SORRY", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading the error message?

Comment: yes!but i don't undestand what is not good!

Comment: The connection timed out. The SQL Server you are trying to connect to is not responding, or you specified the wrong server. Is your SQL Server running?

Comment: There's lots of things that could cause a conneciton proble, this article tries to cover many of them: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

Comment: yes! i used this server many times in my program! but only for this i get that error !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usually I got this error message in two cases: if connection to db disappeared or if I executed long executing sql. In your case I suppose that problem may be caused by big size of the image file. First of all I recommend you to check do you have connection to db at all, and then I propose you to play with smaller images for example image of one byte.

Comment: There is a difference between a Connection-Timeout and a Command-Timeout.  Long running queries would hit the Command-Timeout I do believe.